# Finding $\sum_{r=1}^{n}{\cot{}^{ - 1}(3r^2-\frac{5}{12})}$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> Find the sum of
>   $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}{\cot{}^{ - 1}(3r^2-\frac{5}{12})}$$

I tried to convert all into 
$\tan {}^{ - 1}(x) $
using 
$\cot {}^{ - 1} (x) = { \tan {}^{ - 1} ( \frac{1}{x} ) }$ 
and then tried to simplify them using property 
$ \tan {}^{ - 1} ( \frac{x - y}{1 - xy} )  = \tan {}^{ - 1} (x) - \tan {}^{- 1} (y)  $
so that some terms cancel each other.

But I do not manage to simplify the problem. What to do?

Comment: Your question seems arduous. Is it known if there is a closed-form solution ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust it is what it is

Comment: But is it known if there is a closed-form solution ?

Comment: The function can be integrated, so you can try the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula.

Comment: @YvesDaoust please help me and post the answer

Comment: I removed the inverse problems tag, which is not relevant for the question. Please see the tag wiki. It does not simply mean any problem with an inverse function.

Comment: @Mohit Where did you find this problem from? If it is a contest problem or something, then people would try to solve it by believing there is a quick solution.

Comment: It is $\tan^{-1}((x-y)/(1+xy))$,  Does that help ?

Comment: @user90369 sorry it was my mistake

Comment: @achillehui sorry I mistyped the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the fix of sign in front of $\frac{5}{12}$ in the question body, the sum becomes pretty simple.

Let $a_{\pm} = 3(r\pm \frac12)$, notice

$$\frac{a_+ - a_-}{1 + a_+ a_-} = \frac{3}{1 + 9(r^2-\frac14)}
= \frac{12}{36r^2 - 5} = \left(3r^2 - \frac{5}{12}\right)^{-1}$$
We have
$$\begin{align}\cot^{-1}\left(3r^2 - \frac{5}{12}\right)
&= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a_+ - a_-}{1 + a_+a_-}\right)
= \tan^{-1}a_+ - \tan^{-1}a_-\\
&= \tan^{-1}(3(r + \frac12)) - \tan^{-1}(3(r - \frac12))
\end{align}
$$
The new sum is a telescoping one and
$$\sum_{r=1}^n
\cot^{-1}\left(3r^2 - \frac{5}{12}\right)
= \tan^{-1}(3(n + \frac12)) - \tan^{-1}(\frac32)$$

Comment: Well done. (+1)

Comment: Sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Using CAS help we have:

$$\sum _{r=1}^n \cot ^{-1}\left(3 r^2-\frac{5}{12}\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{6 n+3}\right)$$

Mathematica code:

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[Sum[D[ArcCot[A*r^2 - 5/12], A], {r, 1, n}] // Normal, 
A] /. A -> 3, n > 0]

(* Luckily, in this case intergration constant C = 0 *)

(*ArcTan[2/3] - ArcTan[2/(3 + 6 n)] *)
```

By the way, we can still find Sum at `n=Infinity`

$$\sum _{r=1}^{\infty } \cot ^{-1}\left(3 r^2-\frac{5}{12}\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\approx 0.588003$$